# Heroku & Delayed Job - Autoscale Branch - RestClient::ResourceNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

SomeController#update (RestClient::ResourceNotFound) "Resource Not Found"

I'm receiving this error (where previously I was not) while trying to enqueue delayed jobs using the autoscale branch of DelayedJob. This does not occur with a none autoscale branch but I'm at a loss to pinpoint what the problem is.

If anyone is experiencing the same or can point me toward a likely cause I'd be grateful for advice.

Comment: check you route file and make sure the route is mapped

Comment: Thanks Sam, it is. Also this is working in development and with another delayedjob branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess...

Is it possible the ResourceNotFound is occurring because the heroku gem cannot find your app when making the API requests to auto-scale? Try using the heroku gem outside your app and make sure you can do operations on your app from within an IRB console with the gem loaded (not Heroku console).

Comment: Thankyou! It turned out that there was a problem with my config variables. I was looking in completely the wrong place, not for the first time. Thanks again.