# Heroku & Delayed Job & Workless - RestClient::ResourceNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

Similar to [Heroku & Delayed Job - Autoscale Branch - RestClient::ResourceNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654509/heroku-delayed-job-autoscale-branch-restclientresourcenotfound/3665065#3665065)

When running a delayed job on Heroku Cedar I get this:

```
RestClient::ResourceNotFound (404 Resource Not Found):
app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

Check my controller at https://gist.github.com/1208004

Everything work on my dev machine.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it:

I had to add a config var to heroku:

```
heroku config:add APP_NAME=myapp
```

:)

Comment: I thought I would die before I fixed this bug ...until I found this post.